# Use a MSHFlexGrid with non-database data and still define the shape

Tags: c++, mfc, ado, mshflexgrid

I am trying to use the Microsoft Hierarchical FlexGrid (MSHFlexGrid) in a Visual C++ (VS 2005).  I have the grid shown, and I can manually add data to the individual cells.  However, according to online [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196029) I've read, I should be able to show the hierarchical nature of the data (hence MSHFlexGrid instead of MSFlexGrid) by defining the SHAPE as the RecordSource.  I can do that fine (by using the put_RecordSource method of the grid object), however I'm at a loss as to how to add the actual data.

I've read that the best way to do this is to use an ADO Data Control (ie ADODC) component and bind it as the DataSource for the Grid. You can then specify "provider=msdatashape;data provider=none;" as the provider of the DataControl and fill it with data.  If I were doing SQL, I'd specify my SELECT query as the RecordSource, then call Refresh() and let the control load the data.

However, my data is in custom objects.  I know what needs to be displayed, I'm just at a loss as to the best way to insert the data into the FlexGrid and still use the built in features of the control.  I'm open to any suggestions, but I need to keep the data local (ie no JET, Access, etc).

Here's some code:

In header:

```
....
// Variable to control the Flex Grid component
CMshflexgrid1 m_grid;  //generated by wizard from the MSHFlexGrid component

// to control the data source hierarchical information
CAdodc1 m_adodc1;
....
```

In cpp:

```
....
BOOL MyDialogClass::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialog::OnInitDialog();

  m_grid.Clear();

  CString strCn = "provider=msdatashape;data provider=none;"; 
  m_adodc1.put_ConnectionString(strCn);

  CString BackupOfRecordSource = "";
  BackupOfRecordSource = m_adodc1.get_RecordSource();

  //CString strShape = "SHAPE APPEND new adInteger As PID, New adVarChar(10) As StudentName, ((SHAPE APPEND new adInteger As ChID, New adVarChar(10) As Course, ((SHAPE APPEND new adInteger As GrndChID, New adBSTR As Description) RELATE  ChID TO GrndChID) As GrandChild) RELATE PID TO ChID) AS Child";
  CString strShape = "SHAPE APPEND new adInteger As PID, New adVarChar(10) As StudentName";
  m_adodc1.put_RecordSource(strShape);
  m_adodc1.Refresh();
  m_grid.Refresh();

  BackupOfRecordSource = m_adodc1.get_RecordSource();  //returns the strShape that I just put in

  //ADD RECORDS HERE!  HOW?

  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample talked about building an ADODB.Recordset and use it as the data source of ADODC. The code you give is building a SQL and use it as the data source of ADODC. I don't think you can replace an ADODB.Recordset with a string.

Comment: Is there any way I could use the recordset and manually add records to it?  The examples I found online show VB6 code to do this, but I have no clue how to do this in C++.

Comment: ADO is COM based, the object you create and the method you call are the same.